# How to run multiple python commands at the same time?

Tags: python, email, subprocess

I've read that subprocess should be used but all the examples i've seen on it shows that it runs only command-line commands. I want my program to run a python command along with another command. The command i want to run is to send an email to a user while a user plays a game i created. i have to have the python commands run at the same time because without doing so nothing else in the game can happen before the email is finished sending so it lags the game. Please help and any input is appreciated.

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you showed some source code ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for threading, which is a relatively deep topic, but this should help you get started: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Basic-Threading-in-Python/

Comment: You might also want to look at [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html)

Answer (score 2):

Threading is talked about in another answer, but you can get basically what you want by using subprocess's Popen command: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

What you'll basically want is this (assuming proc is initialized somewhere in the game loop):

```
#...game code here...

args = [command_name_as_string, arg_1_to_command, arg_2_to_command, etc.]
proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

Then, you'll go back to your game loop. At some point in the game loop, you can put in something like this:

```
if proc:
    proc.poll()
    if proc.returncode:
        #...do whatever you want with the process output here, which can 
        # be accessed with proc.stdin, proc.stderr, and so on...
    proc = None
```